# Taglib errors/warnings

Tags: c, error-handling, taglib, id3-tag

I'm using the c bindings for [taglib 1.6.3](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html). When opening a file with `taglib_file_new`, messages are printed to stderr. How can I control and use these messages? In particular, I would like to catch and handle some of the errors, and secondly I want to TURN OFF the verbose logging to stderr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't catch them, but if you compile TagLib in release mode (`cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`), the messages won't be printed.

Comment: Thanks I'm about to try this. I added taglib straight from the repositories with apt-get. Why is the default mode debug mode instead of release mode?

Comment: I don't know, that's just how CMake does this by default.

Answer (score 1):

You could effectively hide the error messages by `reopen`:ing `stderr`. If you want to silence it totally, you could redirect it to some kind of null device or internal log file. Otherwise, I guess that you would need to filter them out.

Another approach would be to modify taglib itself, which should work as the source is provided.